Creating ranking from value of different attribute in QGIS Field calculator
I have a set of values (differ_per) which I would like to rank (ranking_top) in descending order. How can I do this using the field calculator in QGIS?

ChatGPT gave me this:
array_find(array_agg("your_column_name"), "your_column_name") + 1


The answer :
array_find(
    array_sort(
        array_agg(  "differ_per"  ),
        true
    ),
    "differ_per" 
) + 1

